# Ford Focus Mk2 acc wire dead

Tags: ford, focus, fuse, wire

I have a 2005 mk2 Ford Focus and the acc wire that comes into the back of the stereo connector has stopped working. Also the electric windows only work with the engine running, not when just the ignition is on. This has only just happened so it seems like a fuse has blown but I can't find which one it might be. I've googled fuse box diagrams but I'm still not 100% sure if I should be looking in the engine fuse box or the one under the glove box.
Does anyone know which one it is?
Cheers

Comment: I've taken every single fuse out and checked it and it's definitely not a fuse. When I turn the ignition on I just get engine light and the coil symbol then when I start the engine they go off and everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually either the owner's handbook has the list or it may be embossed in the plastic cover of the fuse box.

But, it may also be worth checking the ignition switch as, if that is not working properly, then you won't get the acc supply even if the fuse is good. Apart from the fuse and the ignition switch there may also be a relay in the circuit.

Comment: The fuse box doesn't have a cover and I was trying to avoid paying out for a manual for what might just be a blown fuse. Will try and check the ignition switch tomorrow. Thanks for your advice.